# Django - automating certain template behaviours

Tags: python, django, django-templates

so essentially I'm a recent convert to Django (and Python for the matter) from PHP. In PHP I'm used to being able to automate many things, especially when writing HTML I used to be able to write such commands such as `<?php get_head() ?>` and it would go fetch all the `meta` information that needs to be inside the `<head></head>` of the HTML page. Is there any such functionality built into Django, or am I going to have to write all the HTML manually?

Thanks so much for any pointers.

Comment: Have you read the django template engine documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to love the `extends` and `block` tags.

Assuming you already got a templated page working, you can extract the basic setup of your HTML page like this:

Create a template called `base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}
      Empty page.
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, in your page template called `page.html`, you can extend your base template and override any blocks:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Page 1 title{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
   Real page content.
   {% block main %}
      Subpage of page.html can also override this main block.
   {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

But Hamish is right, do checkout the doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Comment: You are right, I am going to LOVE `extends` and `block` tags <3<3 I will go read the rest of the docs as soon as possible. Thank you very much for taking a moment to answer!

Comment: This worked like a charm and made me super duper happy. So happy! So so so happy. <3 Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! If you are interested, as a next step, I would also recommend checking out HAML (http://haml.info/) and it's Django port Hamlpy (https://github.com/jessemiller/HamlPy).